# Making a generic Query, how?

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4, entity, entity-sql

Here is my working Code:

```
var queryString = "SELECT VALUE c " +
                  "FROM EMI_ERPContext.Customer AS c " +
                  "WHERE c.FirstName='Emanuel'";
ObjectQuery<Customer> customers = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Customer>(queryString);
```

This code works fine.
But I would like to be able, make this available for any Type. At the moment it works only for Customer. Making the **queryString** dynamic is easy, but how I would call this Line:?

```
ObjectQuery<ANYTYPE> anytypeObjects = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<ANYTYPE>(queryString);
```

Is there a way to call the CreateQuery, without needing to give a specific Type or is there easy way I can make this work? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it.. , using

```
ObjectQuery<dynamic> anytypeObjects = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<dynamic>(queryString);
```

works fine!